# How to fix invalid identifier for join in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an invalid identifier issue while solving this problem: List out driver name, age,position,average trip rating for this particular month: April

this is what I have tried in my sql.

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE driver (
>     driverID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY, 
>     Dname VARCHAR2(20),
>     DNRIC CHAR(14),
>     Dgender CHAR(1),
>     DDOB DATE,
>     Dmobile CHAR(11),
>     DcarNo CHAR(6),
>     Dstart DATE,
>     Dstop DATE,
>     Dgrade CHAR(6),
>     DLicence CHAR(4)
>  );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE booking (
>     BookID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
>     PID NUMBER(4),
>     driverID NUMBER(4),    
>     PickLoc VARCHAR2(13),
>     DropLoc VARCHAR2(13),
>     TDate DATE,
>     TTime NUMBER(4),
>     RideFare CHAR(6),
>     TollOther CHAR(6),
>     cancelDate DATE,
>     TripRating NUMBER(1), 
>     PayMethod CHAR(15),
>   FOREIGN KEY (PID) references passenger (PID),
>   FOREIGN KEY (driverID) references driver (driverID)
>  );
>
>
>
> SELECT Dname as driver, 
> floor(months_between(sysdate,driver.DDOB)/12) as age,
> Dgrade as position,
> rating
> FROM driver
> LEFT JOIN 
> (SELECT driverID, avg(TripRating) as rating
> FROM booking group by driverID
> where (TDate between '01-Apr-2019' and '30-Apr-2019')
> order by rating) 
> booking on driver.driverID = booking.bookingID
> ```

im getting an invalid identifier on last line

Comment: Since you got that error message--What are the identifiers in the last line & do the aliases you mention have the columns you mention? PS WHERE comes before GROUP BY. ORDER BY in a subquery without LIMIT/TOP has no meaning. Tables have no row order. Result sets [sic] do. PS A [mre] should have the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @ShuYi . . . Your code is clearly not MySQL syntax so I changed the tag to Oracle.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Find write-time errors by cutting out code until they go away. Time to read an introduction to select statements instead of guessing at changes to code that someone else wrote for you in another answer. PS You were told in a comment on your last question before you posted this that "group by has to appear after a where statement in a query" and "Oracle doesn't allow using an order by clause in such a subquery".

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name for a column alias and a table  you should use

```
 SELECT Dname as driverName, 
floor(months_between(sysdate,driver.DDOB)/12) as age,
Dgrade as position,
rating
FROM driver
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT driverID, avg(TripRating) as rating
    FROM booking
    where TDate between '01-Apr-2019' and '30-Apr-2019'
    group by driverID
) booking on driver.driverID = booking.driverID
order by rating
```

The order by inside the subquery have not sense
you should place the clause at the outer  level

Comment: check better .. the code you are using  .. i have check my suggestion the the open/closing sequence of the () is right

Comment: answer upated because there was a wrog positon for group by in subquery

Comment: fixed. but still, booking.bookingid invalid identifier

Comment: you ahve not bookingID is subqiery but driverID .. answer  update with driverID in ON clause

Comment: but the column inside 'rating' is empty....should have output their average rating in april...

Comment: I.m not in your data  ..  i can only look at sintax of your code  .. you  have asked for errors  and my code .. solve only   these  error  ..

Answer (score 0):

The columns in the sub query to the left side of your JOIN are called driverID and rating. So, use

```
 on driver.driverID = booking.driverID
```

and things should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the subquery does not have an alias (as mentioned in other answers).  I want to point out that you don't need a subquery at all.  You can write the query as:

```
SELECT d.Dname as driver, 
       floor(months_between(sysdate, d.driver.DDOB) / 12) as age,
       d.Dgrade as position,
       avg(b.TripRating) as rating
FROM driver d LEFT JOIN 
     booking b
     ON b.driverID = d.bookingID AND
        b.tDate >= DATE '2019-04-01' AND
        b.tDate < DATE '2019-05-01'
GROUP BY d.Dname, 
         floor(months_between(sysdate, d.DDOB) / 12),
         d.Dgrade
ORDER BY rating;
```

Some notes on the query, however you write it:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  These should be abbreviations for the table names.
- Oracle supports the `DATE` keyword for introducing date constants in the standard YYYY-MM-DD format.
- Note that I changed the date logic to use `>=` and `<` rather than `BETWEEN`.  This is particularly important in Oracle where the `DATE` data type has a time component, so your logic might miss `Tdates` on `'2019-04-30'` if they have a time component.
- With a `LEFT JOIN` the filtering conditions should be in the `ON` clause (your version where they are in a subquery also works).

Comment: line 9 not properly end :(

Comment: @ShuYi . . . What row is line 9?